# Convert BLOB image to binary value

Tags: php, sql, binary, phpmyadmin

I uploaded an image in a database in phpadmin into the column image of type blob.Therefore i want to select the binary code of the image so i do this

```
SELECT CONVERT( `image` 
USING binary ) AS image
FROM `license` 
WHERE `l_name` = 'lamen'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

the results are similar to what i am looking for, but i dont think i get the pure binary as it returns this.

�PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0h\0\0\0f\b\0\0\0�tC�\0\0\0sRGB\0���\0\0\0gAMA\0\0�� 
UT+M�TQ�K�+�k(�\r�\0\0\0\0IEND�B`�

Just a bunch of mess. i deleted alot of the lines cause its just this similar code.

HOWEVER. if i say 
     `SELECT CONVERT(`image
     `USING binary) as image from`license`where`l_name`='lamen'`

it returns image and under it [BLOB-413 bytes]

and if i click it i get

`SELECT * 
FROM`license
`WHERE CONVERT(`image
`USING utf8 ) = CAST( 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 AS BINARY ) ;`

Which i suspect is what i want...i however...cant get my select statement to return that code even if i say 
`select CONVERT(image USING utf8 )`

Thansk for the help

PS.I know its easier to upload the image to a file and just save the path. and already know how to do this. I however am trying something and want to use this way.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the image as a string, you don't need to actually convert it at all, or worry about the charset. It looks like you're over complicating it.

Use one of the BLOB types as your field type (BLOB / MEDIUMBLOB etc) and make sure you escape the string when you insert into the database. These field types are not charset dependent but are "BINARY" types.

If you're using the old mysql_() functions, use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape the value, but if you're using PDO or mysqli_() then user prepared statements as this does the escaping for you (nice and easy).

When you select, no need to do anything then either - it should just work.

Comment: the image field is BLOB and i manually uploaded it using the GUI of phpmyadmin.when i say "select image from table" i get nulls i my program

Comment: 1) Check the size. BLOB is limited to 64K (65,535 bytes), so you may need something larger. 2) What does PHPMyAdmin show when you browse? phpMyAdmin does convert to BINARY and you should be able to see the data as a binary string in hex (begins with 0x).

Comment: when i browse image field shows [BLOB-413 Bytes]. IT does not show the binary that begins with 0x (cause thats what i was expecting). I only see that '0x' when i do what i stated i do in the first post. Thanks for helping so far

Comment: In this case, it's not NULL - it's your code that's wrong after that - just do a straight SELECT with NO conversion of any type. `SELECT image FROM database`.  You should then be holding the same string as you inserted (assuming you inserted into a BLOB). If you need it in the `where` then just escape and don't convert to binary - you don't have to copy phpMyAdmin!

Comment: I had a straight select but it wasnt working thats why i decided to format it. This is the orginal code.
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id,CONVERT(`image` USING binary),license_num,l_name,f_name,DATE_FORMAT(birth_d,\'%e-%m-%Y\') AS birth ,DATE_FORMAT(expires,\'%e-%m-%Y\') AS     
expires,license_type,license_status,CASE WHEN CURDATE( ) >= `expires`  THEN \'Expired\' ELSE \'Not Expired\' END AS status FROM license WHERE l_name=?');
                $stmt->bind_param("s",$l_name);
        

  Hope its not a mess

Comment: $result[] = array(
           "image"=>$image,       
    );

Comment: You still have "convert" there. It is a binary field. It is chracter set irrelevent. Just do a straight SELECT. (But bonus points for using prepared statements - this also rules out other potential errors!)

Comment: ok, but when i say `SELcET image from table` i get null for image :(

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong somewhere. You probably need to provide your entire function (s) for saving and retrieving. There is data there - I guess you're not saving the right thing.

Comment: ok sir, working on it a bit more. Will provide more information later